# Which products require EMC certificate?

Tags: emc, fcc, certification, ce, regulations

What are the guidlines (or where can I find them) for which products require EMC testing certificate? I know that this determined per country, so for starters let's go with the US.

My product contains a LIPO 3.7v battery, vibration motor, processor and accelerometer, no wireless transmission whatsoever. Will I need to have it tested?

Comment: The fact that your device doesn't have a transmitter doesn't mean it does not need to meet certain requirements regarding EMC. For example, a DC motor might have brushes which cause sparking when in use and that causes EMC emissions. A simple capacitor across the motor's terminals might be enough to fix that though. In the US, the FCC deals with this, have you looked on their website?

Comment: Anything that carries an oscillator in it probably needs EMC certs. Even a typical AM receiver using an IF requires it. Do you have anything that oscillates and therefore might emit? The processor alone would seem to say so (though I've heard of asynchronous processors.) There are dithering oscillators, pseudo-spread spectrum, that can help a lot, here.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, radio frequency emissions must conform the FCC regulations. That means the US code of of federal regulations, title 47 (CFR 47). If the product is not designed to be a radio transmitting device, that applicable rules are contained in part 15 (CFR 47 part 15). If you search "CFR 47 part 15" you will find a link to the applicable regulations. The types of products that require certification are listed in CFR 47 part 15. In many cases, builder can test the product and make a statement that it conforms. Nothing else is required. Regardless of any test or statement, if unintentional emissions interfere with licensed radio transmission, the owner can be ordered to turn the offending device off.

Comment: Notably Canada and Mexico have similar technical requirements as US FCC, but may need a separate license per country.

Answer (score 2):

In EU<sup>1)</sup> electronic products either sort under the:

- [The Radio Equipment Directive 2014/53/EU](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32014L0053) in case they contain any form of wireless electronics, or
- [The EMC Directive 2014/30/EU](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32014L0030) for everything else that contains active electronics but doesn't contain wireless/radio signals.

Each directive comes with a vast list of harmonized technical EN standards, that may or may not apply to your product. You need to write an EU Declaration of Conformity for the product stating which directives it fulfils, and optionally also which harmonized standards that apply.

Both RED and EMC directives offer different ways to demonstrate compliance, you can make an internal conformance test in most cases, described in Annex II in either directive. (RED calls the three different ways to demonstrate compliance "module A, B and C".)

So a 3rd party test isn't mandatory, but you need to fulfil the relevant directives and standards for the product. In case it is found non-conforming by the authorities, you'll be in trouble regardless of if it was tested by a neutral party or not.

---

<sup>1)</sup> European Union + most other European countries such as UK, Norway, Switzerland, Turkey etc. The EU directives are often also generally accepted in most of the Middle-East, several countries in Africa, South America and Oceania.